# Conversion: uid_t to string, off_t to string

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, systems-programming

I am currently writing a systems programming homework and in one part i need to get some information of a file in a directory.

for the stat of file, we have `ctime()` function which converts `time_t` type to `string` and returns a pointer to it.

but how about the `uid_t` and `off_t` types? I searched through to internet and couldnt find any function.. Or if there does not exist any function, can you tell me how to implement such a function please?

Answer (score 4):

Both are defined as arithmetic types (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), and in practice are positive and integral.  So you can just cast to unsigned long long, and use sprintf with "%llu" to convert to string.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` and `off_t` are just unsigned integral types. (Edit: `off_t` is a long? See, the lesson is, check your headers!)

So use `sprintf` (or whatever) to convert them using the "%i" format specifier.

On edit: crap, you changed `size_t` to `uid_t` while I was answering. `uid_t` is defined in `types.h`; look there. (It's also an unsigned integral type, but an `unsigned short`.)

Comment: I think the actual lesson is that these are different sizes on different systems.

Comment: Yes, which is why I wrote "check your headers". Emphasis on "your". :)

Answer (score 1):

Linux' [snprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) supports the 'z' format specifier for values of type `size_t`. Not sure how portable this is, you'll need to inspect the "CONFORMS TO" section closely.

For `off_t`, you might need to cast to the largest unsigned integer type, i.e. `unsigned long` and use a "lu" specifier.

Answer (score 0):

`off_t` is a `long int`: format = "%ld"

`size_t` is an `unsigned int`: format = "%u"

You can use these format in `sprintf` function to convert into a char*.

Comment: I don't believe they're guaranteed to be those types on all platforms.

Comment: You're right, but as they are not format for off_t or size_t, this is the only solution. This can be improved using pre processing test to know the platform.

Comment: Why can't you just widen the values to unsigned long long?

Answer (score 0):

Using gcc 5.4.0 the following line:

`printf("user #%ld did this or that!\n", uid);`

raised the following warning:

`..main.c:133:9: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uid_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]`

I would suggest you to do the same and check your compiler's output. =)